# what is the regular expression for this

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to parse this

```
(adv) much (thanks)
```

I want to eliminate the words and the bracket (adv) but not (thanks)

the condition is:
inside bracket, and word length inside bracket is 1-5 characters

I am using preg_match in PHP

Comment: Only in the beginning of the string or anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$matches = NULL;
preg_match("/\([^\)]{1,5}\)/", "(adv) much (thanks)", $matches);
var_export($matches);
array (
 0 => '(adv)',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = '(adv) much (thanks)';
$str = preg_replace('/\(\w{1,5}\) ?/', '', $str);
```